# How to convert WAV to AAC on Android

Tags: android, audio, wav, aac

Is it possible to convert a wav file to aac encoded file?
And if so, does anyone have a example or knows a library for this on android?

Comment: You could probably do that with the [`MediaCodec` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html).

Comment: Ye i looked into that, but the problem is i need to support android version 4.0. MediaCodec is added in 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so simple to achieve but possible.
By the way you ask, I understand that you already know how to get the WAV raw data (the actual bytes).
In order to encode the AAC you will probably need to encode the WAV to PCM and then to AAC.

Try looking for one of the many audio encoding libraries out there that can convert WAV to PCM and PCM to AAC (or maybe you'll get lucky and find one that converts WAV directly to AAC).
He're an example for one that knows to convert PCM to AAC:
http://www.betaful.com/2012/04/encoding-aac-audio-in-android/

Comment: Typically, the audio data in a WAV file will already be uncompressed PCM.

Comment: Not necessary, WAV is just the container. You can many types of possible encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV

Comment: thnx for Library, if i'm right my wav files are already PCM. I will look into the library.